# Laravel Eloquent belongsTo not working

Tags: php, laravel

I can't make the `belongsTo` relationship work (or I am using wrong relationship).

My database structure (simplified):

**pages**:

```
id | title | main_image
-----------------------
1  | Test  | 5
```

**media**:

```
id | filepath
-----------------------
5  | uploads/test.jpg
```

So I want to be able to do `$page->main_image` and it would return me instance of the Media model, so I could use `$page->main_image->filepath` etc.

In the `Page` model I have the following:

```
    public function main_image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Modules\Media\Models\Media', 'id', 'main_image');
    }
```

But when I do `$page->main_image` I just get `int 5`. Am I using the wrong relationship here?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `dd($page->main_image)` output?

Comment: Outputs same **5**

Comment: Try `return $this->belongsTo('App\Modules\Media\Models\Media', 'main_image');` 
I think you got the params wrong for the `belongsTo`method

Comment: @mazedlx Changed it, still getting just `int 5`. However, if I do `$page->main_image()->first()` (with your suggested change) it does seem to return a `Media` instance, why is it not triggering on the normal get?

Comment: use `hasOne` instead of `belongsTo`, it seems this is a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: You should not give the foreign key and the relation the same name.

Comment: I've changed it to `return $this->hasOne('App\Modules\Media\Models\Media', 'id', 'main_image');` and it still produces same results: `$page->main_image` is `int 5` and `$page->main_image()->first()` produced the right result. However, it is not a 1:1 relationship as many pages can have same media object as *main_image*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing `$page->main_image` Eloquent will only try to find the `main_image()` relation if there is no attribute with the same name. But you already have a column name `main_image`. So you should either rename the attribut (column name) or the relation. I would rename the column to `main_image_id`.

The priority/order of what is to be returned is:

- Public object property (`public $main_page`)
- GetAccessor (`$page->getMainPage()`)
- Table column/attribute (`$page->attributes['main_page']`)
- Attribute/column from table (`$this->attributes['main_page']`)
- Loaded relation (`$this->relations['main_page']`)
- Unloaded relation (`$this->main_page()->get()`)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! So if I want it accessible on `$page->main_image` I should use the an accessor method?

Comment: I would rather rename the column name to `main_image_id`